# Remote WebDriver with Ruby issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, webdriver

Folks,

I am trying to setup remote webdriver in Ruby. I have worked extensively with Selenium before using Java but I am really new to Ruby. This is how my code looks like:

```
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :url => "http://mysite:4444/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox)
@driver.navigate.to homepage
```

The problem that I am seeing is the browser fires up on the remote machine but opens with a blank page. When I run the same code on the local machine the page opens fine. I am not sure what I am missing here.

This is the webdriver gem that I am using selenium-webdriver (0.2.1, 0.1.4) and I am using ruby  ruby-1.9.2-p180

Comment: Is the webserver you're testing on A) a third machine, or b) the local machine, which is not the :remote machine. It could be that the remote machine can't reach the webserver. Just wanna make sure it's not something simple before we dive into the docs.

Comment: Tim, thanks a lot, it was something very simple and I caught it today. It was actually a simple bug in my ruby code.

Answer (score 0):

First download [Selenium Server](http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar) and run in local machine then

configure setup method like,

```
def setup
  @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :url => 'http://192.168.0.188:4444/wd/hub', :desired_capabilities => :chrome)
  #@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
  @base_url = "http://www.google.com/"
  @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
  @verification_errors = []
end
```

then run test cases from remote pc, will get executed in local machine. If you have any problem let me know.